# OpenCV's .clone() and OpenMP throwing random unhandled exceptions

Tags: c++, opencv, openmp

The constructor for my class is as follows:

```
Foo::Foo(const cv::Mat &img){
        _img = img.clone();
}
```

I am essentially trying to run 80 templates across 80 different images and trying run an omp parallel for loop, which works fine most of the time.

```
int imgNum = 80;
std::vector<cv::Mat> imgStack(imgNum);
setImgStack(imgStack);
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 0; i < imgNum; i++)
    shared_ptr<Foo> test(new Foo(imgStack[i]));
```

However around like 5% I randomly get an unhandled exception thrown on the .clone() line.

> Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCE4BA982C (opencv_world300.dll) in test_TemplateMatching.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008.

Pointing to here (on mat.inl.hpp):

```
inline
Mat Mat::clone() const
{
    Mat m;
    copyTo(m);
    return m;
}
```

I want to emphasize that when this occurs it is unpredictable.  I can run this on thousands of images and record where it fails.  Run it again and I get different fail locations.  It also never occurs if I remove omp, however on the dataset I'm using that doubles the time to an extremely unreasonable amount.

Is there some sort of issue with cloning an image while using omp that I am not aware of?

Comment: Maybe unrelated, but you should probably take `img` as `const cv::Mat&`.

Comment: I've tried both, I just posted the latest attempt here.  Apologies for that.

Comment: Without having too a strong understanding of OpenCV, what you **show** looks fine as you only operate on `const` shared objects. However, there may be issues in code that you don't show - to avoid that, pleas provide a [mcve].

Comment: The problem can be reproduced with what has been given.  The keyobject isn't necessary to reproduce so I can remove that.